# application of the discrete maximum principle for harmonic functions (markov chains)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk, harmonic-functions

Given a connected and locally finite network R=(V,E, c), let P be the stocastic matrix of the random walk on R. Take $ B \subseteq V$ such that $B^C$ is finite and connected. Take $h_B: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\, $  s.t.  $\, h_B(x)=c \, \,  \forall x \in \partial B$.
Prove that $h: V\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, the harmonic extension of $h_B$,  is s.t. $h(x)=c \, \forall x \in B$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.